# PowerBI Increments on slicer not working (GENERATESERIES)

Tags: filter, powerbi, increment, slicers

I have created a Parameter with GENERATESERIES in order to filter amounts of two fact tables by using increments:

```
GENERATESERIES(MIN(MINX(one_fact,one_fact[amount]),MINX(two_fact,two_fact[amount])), MAX(MAXX(one_fact,one_fact[amount]),MAXX(two_fact,two_fact[amount])), 250000)
```

But the Slicer only shows the increment for "Single Value" not for "Greater then or equal to", as i need it:
[image: SingleValue]
[image: GreaterThenOrEqual]

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, or I don't think the slicer supports increments when the slider is used (except for Single Value).

However, suggest you keep it as Single Value and handle the `greater than or equal to` via dax expression in Measures.